# How to act on a single list item regarding the new Android guidelines?

Tags: android, listview, selection

The new (ICS) [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html) were published.
It is written there:

> If you don't support multi-selection within a list, long press should do nothing.

I don't support multi-selection and still want to support acting on a single list item.

**How should I support acting on a single list item?**

Comment: Do you have an example situation where this functionality is required?

Comment: Simplified: File browsing without multiple selection. Click should view the file or go into folder and **other context actions can be to share the file or delete it**. Opening the file may go outside of the app, so I CANNOT give an option to share/delete it after clicking the file.

Comment: Another example can be a remix music view. Clicking on a song plays it using a user chosen player (or default). Other contextual options can be remixing the song or sharing it.

Comment: With both of your examples, the extra options would also apply to other items in the list, so you should make it multi-selectable. For example, you may want to share or delete more than one file at a time. The same with music, you may want to mix or share more than one song.

Comment: As a developer, you wouldn't add the support of mixing 4 songs or sharing 5 files simultaneously in the first version of the app, right? It requires a different view (with checkboxes) and a different implementation to the actions as well. Can we conclude that acting on a single item is viable scenario?

Comment: Perhaps it's a scenario that Google don't want people to explore? Do you have an example that would benefit the end user?

Comment: Giltch, you have a point! In real life though, and not in ideal UX, there are actions on a Single-selection item. Google themselves know that a lot of things that they do is not ideal and have compromises. I'm searching for a compromise here.

Answer (score 0):

You can support multi-selection at a basic level and provide context actions in the action bar for users that long press an item. (Limit selection to one entry.)

Alternatively you should provide such context controls from within the item itself.

For example if you have a list of music that you do not wish to make multi-selectable, the user can click a song to preview it, and in a new view see the options to queue/delete/etc.

With the original suggestion the user can long press the song, and then perform these actions from the action bar.

The obvious problem is that every action is now 1 further click or unnecessary action away. (For a non multi-selectable list anyway.)

Comment: Part of your suggestion contradicts the guidelines. Can you please refer to the guidelines in your answer?

Comment: Referring to the guidelines, your proposal is to give the additional options in a different view, right? The disadvantage is that the other view (after the click) may be of another app. See my example in the question's comments.